# Powershell Import-Module SqlServer Error

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2014, powershell-5.0

I am trying to download the 'SqlServer' module, I recently upgraded Powershell from 4.0 to 5.0. I have set the execution policy to `RemoteSigned`. This is on a Windows 2012 R2 Server. I am getting this error.

> Import-Module : The specified module 'SqlServer' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

I want to download the `SqlServer` module.

Comment: Hi, have you tried this ? http://guidestomicrosoft.com/2015/01/13/install-sql-server-powershell-module-sqlps/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use comment right now so I'll just write it down here. Nowadays SQLServer module is shipped with SSMS releases and SQLPS module is shipped with SQL Server itself. I would suggest you download [latest SSMS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and it should work fine. Note that there's an earlier version of SQLServer module available in [SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676).

Comment: That would make sense. I have SSMS 2016 downloaded my personal Win10 laptop and Import-Module SqlServer succeeded fine. But on the servers we do not have SSMS 2016.

Comment: Then download it via the feature pack, it's not the latest one but it'll work.